# overlaying text over video

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want to overlay a video with some text. The html/css works fine in Safari and Firefox - but in Chrome the text disappears on scrolling. Here is a quick video showing the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTJs8.jpg

The HTML/CSS is quite straight forward:

```
<figure>
  <video preload autoplay loop muted playsinline src="https://zachholman.com/video/utc-one.mp4" poster="https://zachholman.com/images/talks/utc/poster-one.jpg">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>

  <h1 style="left:8vw; top:6vw; font-size: 5vw; color:blue;">
    <div>What is</div>
    <div>Time?</div>
  </h1>
</figure>
```

and

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
}

figure video {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
figure h1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/tcurdt/pen/MXJpPr/

Is this a well know bug in Chrome? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in a recent build. Updating Google Chrome fixed it. So simple.